# LDAP users list using php

Tags: php, ldap

```
function getUsers() { 
    $process = new process();
    $process->s_Host('domain.com');
    $process->s_Domain('domain.com');   
    $process->s_LdapSecure(false);

    if($process->LdapConn()){
        if($process->LdapBind()){        
            $filter = "(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)";       
            $search = @ldap_search($filter);     
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($search);    
            return $entries;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to return any values from the search, i dont know how to search or get all users.

The connection is working fine.

Comment: You might want to get rid of the @ sign on that php function call, since it will turn off any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be

```
$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
```

This article might be of interest: [LDAP Query Basics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(EXCHG.65).aspx)

Comment: Is it common for all, i mean should we set something for person or user outta there.